# Using the Tag Cloud badge model for non technical type

Tags: discussion

My wife is looking to set up a natural bodybuilding site.  I told here to take a look at SO model but she seamed to think that non tech people would understand the tag model.  I was wondering if you think non techs could use a similar system as opposed to the standard BBS.

Comment: You mean ANSI art login screens and no mouse support?  +1 from me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're all too techy here to give you our view on how non-techs take to tags.

This is far more appropriate on Stack Exchange. It's a productised version of SO and has been [running some non-tech audience sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-sites) for a time now.

But, if the audience favours organisation, tags help out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is a "the chicken or the egg" problem.

On the other side:
Hopefully as more and more (web) applications use tags more non tech people will get used to it.

You can only find out if your audience is ready for tags if you do some usability testing.